# Add assets to pipeline from engine without require it in main application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I need to add assets to pipeline from moutable engine (JS and CSS) but i can't require it in application.js.

Main app:
main_app/app/assets/application.js

Engine:
my_engine/app/assets/my_engine/application.js

How i can get this to work ?

Comment: Is my_engine local to main_app, e.g. `my_engine/main_app/app`?

Why is `application.js` not under `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`? Same question applies to an engine.

Comment: i think sprockets need to have a require directive in order to load your assets: https://github.com/rails/sprockets#managing-and-bundling-dependencies